# Is there a simple PHP development server?

Tags: php, webserver

When writing web apps in Python, it's brain dead easy to run a development server. Django and Google App Engine (GAE) both ship with simple servers.

The main feature I'm looking for is no configuration. I want something like the GAE dev server where you just pass the directory of the app as a parameter when the server is started.

Is there a reason that this is more difficult with PHP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use XAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html
Its easy to install and config.

EDIT:
since PHP 5.4 (which was released 2 years after this answer) there's a built-in web-server. Today this is inaccurate, please use the method provided by k0pernikus in his answer.

Comment: I'd be happier if I didn't need to run Apache, but this looks like the way to do it. Currently, I use Nginx / MySQL, but I only touch it every few months, so I don't feel like screwing around with configuring anything.

Comment: this should not be the accepted answer. php -S is what he wanted and you suggest installing a full featured webserver suite with database and all.

Comment: @roothahn at the time of the answer the latest php version was 5.3.3. That version did not have a built-in web server. I agree with you today, but the dev server did arrive only 2 years after this answer. I have clearly stated this almost 3 years ago in the comments of the highest ranking answer.

Answer (score 223):

Actually PHP 5.4.0 recently presented its [built-in web server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

```
cd ~/public_html
php -S localhost:8000
```

Comment: Well, at the time of my answer this didn't exist, but its clearly the better way of solving the problem.

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer.

Comment: Totally agree with Alphaa. This is a hell of a lot simpler than installing LAMP / XAMPP.

Comment: `-t` to set the document root (relative path) if you want to run this from your project's cwd. For example, if you had a build process that output the public browser code to a `./dist/` folder: `php -S localhost:8000 -t dist`

Answer (score 21):

If it's a feasible option on whatever platform you're using, PHP 5.4 has a Django-like [development server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php).

You may also want the [snippet](https://gist.github.com/3057918) I use to detect the development server and replicate the two most common uses of mod_rewrite. (Hiding `index.php` in URLs and passing static files through to be served)

(Yes, there is a built-in command-line switch for that, but it doesn't quite match the mod_rewrite snippet most people use and caused spurious 404 errors for me because of that mismatch.)

Answer (score 8):

#### Try using *batch* file

1. Open notepad
2. php -S localhost:8000
3. save file as .bat extension => server.bat
4. now click on `server.bat`, your server is ready on http://localhost:8000.

#### DEP

if you got error `php not recognize any internal or external command`
               then goto environment variable and edit path to php.exe

```
"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3"
```

Answer (score 7):

Update: I've developed a docker based version that I have started using instead of easy_php_dev: [localdev](https://github.com/ctcherry/localdev)

[easy_php_dev](https://github.com/ctcherry/easy_php_dev) makes multi-site php development very easy and fast. Only limitation is it is designed only for OSX. Disclosure: I'm the author.

Answer (score 5):

When I need a quick php web server for local testing I use [QuickPHP](http://www.zachsaw.co.cc/?pg=quickphp_php_tester_debugger)

Comment: This seems to be Windows only.

Answer (score 5):

We have developed a very small development server which has a similar behavior as django development server.

The software is called [sng](https://github.com/ravelsoft/node-sng) and work with php and nginx. It is made in javascript and [nodejs](http://nodejs.org), you can install it very easily with npm :

```
npm install sng
```

Answer (score 2):

[AppServ](http://www.appservnetwork.com/) has always setup everything you need nicely!