# ajax - can't retrieve data (same domain)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

EDIT: Cavid Kərimov's answer does work. Setting the form as below does also work.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;"></form>
```

I'm trying to retrieve a simple string of text from a PHP file using jQuery and AJAX as shown below:

index.html

```
$.get("echo.php", function(data, status) {
    console.log("success: " + data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    console.log("failed: " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
});
```

echo.php

```
<?php

    echo "echoed from php successfully";

?>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
failed: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

I googled around for a bit and apparently this happens because of the Same-origin Policy, however I'm sure that isn't the case here because the HTML and PHP file are stored in the exact same folder on the server.

[image: server directory (can't post images because it requires 10 reputation)]

Comment: Have you tried to just open php file in your browser?

Comment: Inspect your network requests (in something like Chrome Devtools). What is it telling you? Can you add a picture of that?

Comment: Good point @SenadMeškin in that case see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004696/is-there-a-simple-php-development-server)

Comment: also log the error message fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {

Comment: open your echo.php in browser and see what it shows you

Comment: just the fact that you do not include a path to a different domain confirms you are not looking in a different origin.  I would try a simple call like 
`... function(d){
  console.log(d)}`
and see what you get, AFTER opening echo.php in a browser first.

Comment: @GabeRogan I'm doing a college project and the teacher gave us an actual working server somewhere in the US which obviously I have no access to except for a FTP account and a database.

Comment: [jQuery Ajax - Status Code 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000609/jquery-ajax-status-code-0)

Comment: @Senad Meškin Yes I tried that and it works. The browser correctly displays the echo string.

Comment: @Andreas I think that may be it. It does get redirected.

doc ready
clicked
id: 1
Navigated to http://www.sportsinitiative.org/TPSIB17/p7/ajax-test/
failed: {"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Comment: @MartimFerreira Your teacher wants you to upload your finished project to that server. While you're developing you need a PHP server on your computer (usually accomplished with `php -S localhost:8000` or software like MAMP or WAMP)

Comment: @GabeRogan The directoy showed in the picture is the actual server directory. I did think about that though. But wouldn't it be pointless if it only worked locally?

Comment: @Andreas Checked out your link, fixed. I'll post the solution in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this and tell us what happened:

```
         $("#go").click(function() {
                console.log("clicked");

                var $id = $("#id").val();
                console.log("id: " + $id);

                $.get("echo.php", function(data) {
                    console.log("success: " + data);
                }).fail(function(data) {
                    console.log("failed: " + data);
                });

             return false;                    
            });
```

Comment: Found a working solution just a second before you posted but also tried yours. It worked great! The page was refreshing before the AJAX request completed (for some reason).

Comment: because you did not write -> return false;